# How to recover corrupted php or html file due to power cut

Tags: windows

I was working on a html file was corrupted due to power cutoff. The file size is same but when I open it with dreamweaver it show blank.
How can I recover this file?

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me just yesterday can you try and open it on Sublime Text 3, if it shows some binary 00's I guess it's irrecoverable unless you have either used a Version Controlling System such as Git Or turned on the system protection on windows, then you can use a system backup restore.